# Es6 react how I can extract const component in other file fail

Tags: ecmascript-6, jsx, admin-on-rest

I have this es6 + jsx code than work fine:

```
// list.js
import React from 'react';
import {
  List,
  Datagrid,
  Filter,
  TextInput,
  NumberField,
  TextField,
} from 'admin-on-rest/lib/mui';

const Filters = props =>
  <Filter {...props}>
    <TextInput source="q" alwaysOn />
  </Filter>
;

export default props => (
  <List {...props} filters={<Filters />} >
    <Datagrid>
      <NumberField source="id" />
      <TextField source="description" />
    </Datagrid>
  </List>
);
```

I want extract Filters definition in a separate source file.

I tried this way:

```
// filters.js
import React from 'react';
import {
  Filter,
  TextInput,
  TextField,
} from 'admin-on-rest';

export default props =>
  <Filter {...props}>
    <TextInput source="q" alwaysOn />
  </Filter>
;
```

and

```
// list.js
import React from 'react';
import {
  List,
  Datagrid,
  Filter,
  TextInput,
  NumberField,
  TextField,
} from 'admin-on-rest/lib/mui';
import Filters from 'filters';

export default props => (
  <List {...props} filters={<Filters />} >
    <Datagrid>
      <NumberField source="id" />
      <TextField source="description" />
    </Datagrid>
  </List>
);
```

I thought the code was equivalent, but in the second case I get a couple of

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
>   (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your
>   component from the file it's defined in.

and finally this error

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Element type is invalid: expected a
>   string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your
>   component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of
>   `StatelessComponent`.

The major indicted is

```
filters={<Filters />}
```

but what would be the correct syntax?

Comment: You always have to provide a relative (or absolute) path to the custom files you want to import. You are potentially importing an npm package with name `filter`. What you want is `import Filters from './filter';` instead.

Comment: `filter.js` vs 'filter**s**'?

Comment: Sorry, it is only a misspelling on report in this post. In my code filename is filters.js . I fixed the post, the question is still open.

Answer (score 1):

My self answer:

my stupid mistake, I tried to import some components from the wrong module (admin-on-rest instead of admin-on-rest/lib/mui).

This question would deserve to be entirely removed from StackOverflow, although it could be useful considering the messages raised entirely misleading.